# when import @config it giving error module not found

Tags: typescript, import, export, config

I have two files logger and crypto in which I am importing config like this 'import  config  from '@config'' is working fine in the logger file but when I try to import config in the crypto file with the same mentioned way it gives the below error
Error: Cannot find module '@config'
Require stack:
{
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/Users/anishabid/Documents/mydocs/local repos/typeScript-boilerplate/src/utils/crypto.ts',
'/Users/anishabid/Documents/mydocs/local repos/typeScript-boilerplate/src/schema/user.ts',
'/Users/anishabid/Documents/mydocs/local repos/typeScript-boilerplate/src/schema/index.ts',
'/Users/anishabid/Documents/mydocs/local repos/typeScript-boilerplate/src/controllers/users.ts',
'/Users/anishabid/Documents/mydocs/local repos/typeScript-boilerplate/src/apis/users.ts',
'/Users/anishabid/Documents/mydocs/local repos/typeScript-boilerplate/src/server/index.ts'
]
}

```
        enter code here
    code in the crypto file 

    import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
    import  config  from '@config';
    
    export const enCrypt = (data: string) => {
      // Encrypt
      const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        data,
        config.CRYPTO_PRIVATE_KEY
      ).toString();
      return ciphertext;
    };
    
    export const denCrypt = (data: string) => {
      // Decrypt
      const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, config.CRYPTO_PRIVATE_KEY);
      const deCryptedValue = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      return deCryptedValue;
    };
    
    export const newDecrypt = (password: string, key: string) => {
      // Decrypt
      const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(password, key);
      const deCryptedValue = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      return deCryptedValue;
    };
    
    export const getEmailHashMD5 = (email: string) => {
      const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(email);
      return hash;
    };

code in logger file 
import { existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import winston from 'winston';
import winstonDaily from 'winston-daily-rotate-file';
import  config  from '@config';
const {LOG_DIR}=config
// logs dir
const logDir: string = join(__dirname, LOG_DIR);

if (!existsSync(logDir)) {
  mkdirSync(logDir);
}

// Define log format
const logFormat = winston.format.printf(({ timestamp, level, message }) => `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`);

/*
 * Log Level
 * error: 0, warn: 1, info: 2, http: 3, verbose: 4, debug: 5, silly: 6
 */
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    }),
    logFormat,
  ),
  transports: [
    // debug log setting
    new winstonDaily({
      level: 'debug',
      datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      dirname: logDir + '/debug', // log file /logs/debug/*.log in save
      filename: `%DATE%.log`,
      maxFiles: 30, // 30 Days saved
      json: false,
      zippedArchive: true,
    }),
    // error log setting
    new winstonDaily({
      level: 'error',
      datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      dirname: logDir + '/error', // log file /logs/error/*.log in save
      filename: `%DATE%.log`,
      maxFiles: 30, // 30 Days saved
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      zippedArchive: true,
    }),
  ],
});

logger.add(
  new winston.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.splat(), winston.format.colorize()),
  }),
);

const stream = {
  write: (message: string) => {
    logger.info(message.substring(0, message.lastIndexOf('\n')));
  },
};

export { logger, stream };
```